# How do I edit Sql Templates in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The original question here was based on a misunderstanding, so I'm modifying it (there were no answers to the original question).  In previous versions of Visual Studio the item templates for Sql items seemed to move about from version to version.  I was having a difficult time finding where they had been placed in VS 2013.  The default template for T-Sql stored procedures produces the following (and that I wanted to modify):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_procedure_name]
    @param1 int = 0,
    @param2 int
AS
    SELECT @param1, @param2
RETURN 0
```

I want to modify this extensive according to our standard in the shop. But I couldn't figure out where they had put the templates this time.

So where are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking around the shop another developer of my acquaintance found the templates for me.  They are located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\Items
```

Mystery solved.